# NEW CLI INSTALL - does not work... tried Alloy and Classic

Tags: exception, appcelerator

```
Summary:
2016-06-24T12:28:18.008Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
2016-06-24T12:28:18.011Z | ERROR  | Cannot read property 'options' of undefined


Details:

brand new installation, Windows 10 64bit

followed: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Tasks

Steps I took:
Downloaded the NODE installer (URL on your downloads page):
node --version
v4.4.5

npm install appcelerator -g
npm WARN installMany request was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.6, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany chalk was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.6, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany progress was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.6, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany tar was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.6, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany which was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.6, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany debug was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.6, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany lodash was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.6, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany request was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.6, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
C:\Users\Ozz Nixon\AppData\Roaming\npm\appcelerator -> C:\Users\Ozz Nixon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appcelerator\bin\appc
C:\Users\Ozz Nixon\AppData\Roaming\npm\appc -> C:\Users\Ozz Nixon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appcelerator\bin\appc
appcelerator@4.2.6 C:\Users\Ozz Nixon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appcelerator
├── which@1.0.8
├── progress@1.1.8
├── async@1.5.2
├── semver@3.0.1
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
├── update-notifier@0.5.0 (is-npm@1.0.0, string-length@1.0.1, chalk@1.1.3, repeating@1.1.3, semver-diff@2.1.0, configstore@1.4.0, latest-version@1.0.1)
├── tar@1.0.3 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8, fstream@1.0.8)
├── request@2.72.0 (aws-sign2@0.6.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, tunnel-agent@0.4.2, oauth-sign@0.8.1, is-typedarray@1.0.0, caseless@0.11.0, stringstream@0.0.5, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, extend@3.0.0, form-data@1.0.0-rc4, tough-cookie@2.2.2, node-uuid@1.4.7, qs@6.1.0, combined-stream@1.0.5, mime-types@2.1.10, aws4@1.3.2, hawk@3.1.3, bl@1.1.2, http-signature@1.1.1, har-validator@2.0.6)
└── lodash@4.11.1

appc setup
Finding latest version ...5.3.0 OK
Validating security checksum OK
Installing ... OK
Compiling platform native modules ...
└ socket.io-client/ws ... OK
└ bunyan/dtrace-provider ...  OK
└ appc-ldapjs/dtrace-provider ...  OK
└ chokidar/fsevents ...  OK
└ chokidar/fsevents ...  OK
Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

? Appcelerator ID: ozznixon@gmail.com
? Appcelerator ID: ozznixon@gmail.com
? Password: ********
Invalid Appcelerator ID and password combination.

Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

? Appcelerator ID: ozznixon@gmail.com
? Password: **************
Invalid Appcelerator ID and password combination.

Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

? Appcelerator ID: ozznixon@gmail.com
? Password: ********

This computer must be authorized before you can complete your login.

? Confirm with authorization code to Email or Phone/SMS? Email to ozznixon@gmail.com

An authorization code was sent to your email at ozznixon@gmail.com

? Please enter the authorization code you received via your email at ozznixon@gmail.com: 7015

This computer is now authorized: Windows Machine ID: 8f61c9c2-dad0-4208-9e4c-c096d20e2894
You can deauthorize this computer by logging out with appc logout

Generating Developer Certificate and Private/Public Keys...
? Do you plan on developing Titanium apps? Yes

Checking your environment...

No Mobile SDK found, downloading ...
New version available! 5.3.0.GA

Downloading http://builds.appcelerator.com/mobile-releases/5.3.0/mobilesdk-5.3.0.GA-win32.zip
  100% [========================================] 0.0s

Extracting SDK to C:\ProgramData\Titanium
  100% [========================================]

Setting Titanium SDK 5.3.0.GA as the default.

Titanium SDK 5.3.0.GA successfully installed!

You have the latest Titanium SDK release 5.3.0.GA
The following JDK issues were found in your environment:

        JDK (Java Development Kit) not installed.
        If you already have installed the JDK, verify your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly set.
        The JDK is required for must be manually downloaded and installed from
        http://appcelerator.com/jdk.

Some issues were detected for your environment

        Please review the above found issues that were detected for your environment.
        You should resolve these issues before building or running a cross platform app.
        You can re-run setup once they are resolved to validate.

appc setup complete!

I downloaded and installed: Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 92 (64-bit)

Then:
appc use
The following versions are available:

5.3.1-2    Not Installed
5.3.0      Installed (Latest) (Active)
5.3.0-47   Not Installed
5.3.0-43   Not Installed
5.3.0-34   Not Installed
5.2.0-265  Not Installed
5.2.2      Not Installed
5.2.0-213  Not Installed
5.2.1      Not Installed
5.2.1-12   Not Installed
5.2.0-55   Not Installed
5.2.0      Installed
5.1.0      Not Installed
5.0.4      Not Installed
5.0.3      Not Installed
5.0.2      Not Installed
5.0.1      Not Installed
5.0.0      Not Installed
4.1.3      Not Installed
4.1.2      Not Installed
4.1.1      Not Installed
4.1.0      Not Installed
5.0.0-50   Not Installed
5.0.0-40   Not Installed
4.0.2      Not Installed
4.1.0-0    Not Installed
4.0.1      Not Installed
4.0.0      Not Installed
4.0.0-rc   Not Installed
1.2.123    Not Installed
0.2.285    Not Installed
0.2.283    Not Installed
0.2.282    Not Installed
0.2.276    Not Installed
0.2.273    Not Installed
0.2.255    Not Installed
0.2.247    Not Installed
0.2.246    Not Installed
0.2.242    Not Installed
0.2.241    Not Installed
0.2.230    Not Installed
0.2.229    Not Installed
0.2.228    Not Installed
0.2.227    Not Installed
0.2.226    Not Installed
0.2.225    Not Installed
0.2.224    Not Installed
0.2.223    Not Installed
0.2.222    Not Installed
0.2.221    Not Installed
0.2.220    Not Installed
0.2.219    Not Installed
0.2.218    Not Installed
0.2.217    Not Installed
0.2.216    Not Installed
0.2.215    Not Installed
0.2.214    Not Installed
0.2.213    Not Installed
0.2.212    Not Installed
0.2.210    Not Installed
0.2.209    Not Installed
0.2.208    Not Installed
0.2.207    Not Installed
0.2.204    Not Installed
0.2.203    Not Installed
0.2.201    Not Installed
0.2.200    Not Installed
0.2.199    Not Installed
0.2.198    Not Installed
0.2.198    Not Installed
0.2.197    Not Installed
0.2.196    Not Installed
0.2.195    Not Installed
0.2.192    Not Installed
0.2.191    Not Installed
0.2.187    Not Installed
0.2.186    Not Installed
0.2.185    Not Installed
0.2.183    Not Installed
0.2.182    Not Installed
0.2.181    Not Installed
0.2.181    Not Installed
0.2.180    Not Installed
0.2.179    Not Installed
0.2.178    Not Installed
0.2.177    Not Installed
0.2.176    Not Installed
0.2.175    Not Installed
0.2.174    Not Installed
0.2.173    Not Installed
0.2.172    Not Installed
0.2.170    Not Installed
0.2.169    Not Installed
0.2.101    Not Installed
0.2.101    Not Installed
0.2.101    Not Installed
0.2.100    Not Installed
0.2.99     Not Installed
0.2.98     Not Installed
0.2.97     Not Installed

Then:
appc new -t titanium --id com.jahbraids.intro -n introproj -p android
A new update (5.3.1-2) is available... Download with appc use 5.3.1-2
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.3.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


*** new completed. ***

Then:
appc run
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.3.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016-06-23T23:51:51.172Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
2016-06-23T23:51:51.175Z | ERROR  | Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Searched, found closed ticket, and tried:
npm install -g titanium
npm WARN deprecated wrench@1.5.8: wrench.js is deprecated! You should check out fs-extra (https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) for any operations you were using wrench for. Thanks for all the usage over the years.
C:\Users\Ozz Nixon\AppData\Roaming\npm\ti -> C:\Users\Ozz Nixon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\bin\titanium
C:\Users\Ozz Nixon\AppData\Roaming\npm\titanium -> C:\Users\Ozz Nixon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\bin\titanium
titanium@5.0.9 C:\Users\Ozz Nixon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium
├── async@1.4.2
├── sprintf@0.1.5
├── humanize@0.0.9
├── semver@5.0.3
├── colors@1.1.2
├── wrench@1.5.8
├── temp@0.8.3 (os-tmpdir@1.0.1, rimraf@2.2.8)
├── fields@0.1.24 (keypress@0.2.1, colors@0.6.2)
├── winston@1.0.2 (cycle@1.0.3, isstream@0.1.2, stack-trace@0.0.9, eyes@0.1.8, async@1.0.0, pkginfo@0.3.1, colors@1.0.3)
├── longjohn@0.2.9 (source-map-support@0.3.2)
├── request@2.62.0 (forever-agent@0.6.1, caseless@0.11.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, oauth-sign@0.8.2, tunnel-agent@0.4.3, stringstream@0.0.5, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, extend@3.0.0, tough-cookie@2.2.2, node-uuid@1.4.7, qs@5.1.0, combined-stream@1.0.5, mime-types@2.1.11, form-data@1.0.0-rc4, http-signature@0.11.0, bl@1.0.3, hawk@3.1.3, har-validator@1.8.0)
├── moment@2.10.6
└── node-appc@0.2.31 (xmldom@0.1.19, semver@5.0.1, node-uuid@1.4.3, adm-zip@0.4.7, diff@2.1.0, optimist@0.6.1, uglify-js@2.4.24, request@2.61.0)

Still: appc run -p android
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.3.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016-06-23T23:57:09.690Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
2016-06-23T23:57:09.695Z | ERROR  | Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Did Update: appc use 5.3.1-2
Before you can continue, the latest Appcelerator software update needs to be downloaded.

Finding version 5.3.1-2 ... OK
Validating security checksum OK
Installing ... OK
Compiling platform native modules ...
└ socket.io-client/ws ... OK
└ bunyan/dtrace-provider ...  OK
└ appc-ldapjs/dtrace-provider ...  OK
└ chokidar/fsevents ...  OK
└ chokidar/fsevents ...  OK
Installed!!

Still: appc run -p android
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.3.1-2
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016-06-24T12:28:18.008Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
2016-06-24T12:28:18.011Z | ERROR  | Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing with us. Please run the following command in the administrative command prompt.

del -rf ~/.appcelerator

del -rf ~/.titanium

npm uninstall -g titanium

npm uninstall -g appcelerator

npm install -g appcelerator

appc use latest

appc setup

appc login

Comment: This may get me there, however, I still get the message that JAVA_HOME is not defined, yet, I check an JDK is installed. Where should JAVA_HOME point? (Windows 10).

Comment: I set it to: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin

Comment: and appc setup still says it is not installed - yet that path is where the JDK is installed. so I tried: JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath  which also fails during appc setup ...

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing looks to be https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23480. This issue has been fixed in the latest 5.3.1 builds of the SDK. You can install this using appc ti sdk install -b 5_3_X -d.

Also for your reference my JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80, after setting this environment variable make sure to restart your command prompt.